# Grouping Data with LINQ Not Working

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query a table and group by field `BillPeriodId` and I'm implementing it in the way the example in this [article](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/grouping-data-with-linq-and-mvc.html) was done. Below is the method doing the grouping

```
public List<BillPeriodLine> GetLinesGroupedByPeriod()
{
    var linesGrouped = _lineRepository.AllIncluding(p => p.BillPeriod)
                                          .GroupBy(pl => pl.BillPeriodId)
                                          .Select(g => new Group<int, BillPeriodLine>
                                          {
                                              Key = g.Key,
                                              Values = g
                                          });
    return new List<BillPeriodLine>(linesGrouped);
}
```

**The Discoverable Type**

```
public class Group<T, K>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

But it underlines `g.Key` with the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'BillTracker.Entities.BillPeriodLine'

It's exactly the way it's done in the example except I'm using lamda expressions. It gives same error using LINQ statements. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Sompne point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have `T` and `K` around the wrong way (or *vice versa*)

```
new Group<int, BillPeriodLine>
```

...

```
public class Group<T, K>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'BillTracker.Entities.BillPeriodLine'

The message says it perfectly, you are trying to push a square peg in a round hole

Comment: I dont see a problem with square peg in round hole. https://giphy.com/embed/J2zwN64xc4wgw

Comment: @JensB when there is a will, there is a way

Comment: @MichaelRandall Nice answer :)

Answer (score 4):

While Michael Randall's answer is perfectly sound regarding the error message, this is only part of the issue.

I guess that you'd like to display the grouped `BillPeriodLine`s in some sort of table as shown in the link you provided. Anyway, you can't simply return a `List<BillPeriodLine>` and assume it to be grouped magically, neither can you create a `List<BillPeriodLine>` from an `IEnumerable<Group<int, BillPeriodLine>>` - which is the type of `linesGrouped`. Presumably what you were trying to do, is to return a `List<Group<int, BillPeriod>>`

```
public List<Group<int, BillPeriodLine>> GetLinesGroupedByPeriod()
{
    var linesGrouped = _lineRepository.AllIncluding(p => p.BillPeriod)
                                      .GroupBy(pl => pl.BillPeriodId)
                                      .Select(g => new Group<int, BillPeriodLine>
                                      {
                                          Key = g.Key,
                                          Values = g
                                      });
    return linesGrouped.ToList();
}
```

This `List<Group<int, BillPeriodLine>>` can be used from a view as shown in the example: The view is iterating over the `List<Group<int, BillPeriodLine>>`. For each `Group<int, BillPeriodLine>` it creates a header for the group and then iterates over all items in `Group<int,BillPeriodLine>.Values` creating a line for each `BillPeriodLine`.

Furthermore (as Michael stated) you'll have to swap the type parameters of your `Group<T,U>` class (or switch the types where you create the `Group<int, BillPeriodLine>`, but I'd prefer the former, since I'd consider the key coming first a bit more intuitive).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was already battling it when I got your response. Thanks for your insight. Spot On!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.